# Execute Single for each element emitted by Flowable

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java

Lets say that I'm reading a file line by line with this mock example

```
Flowable.fromArray("a","b","c","d")
```

Now I want to send each of these lines to backend. Lets use this mock observable to simplify:

```
Single.timer(1, TimeUnit.Seconds).map{true}
```

This returns true to emulate successful response.

I want to continue sending lines one by one, **waiting for a success signal before sending another**.

Would this be possible ?
What is the cleanest solution ?

Comment: Is using the `zip` operator an option?

Comment: @Progman Don't think so. In zip both observables are executed at once, and their results are combined. I want to provide the result of A to B, execute B and go back get another element from A

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of how the events/data should be generated based on the inputs you have. Include some kind of diagram which show when these sources are generating their signal based on a timeline.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want [`concatMapSingle`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Flowable.html#concatMapSingle-io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions.Function-):

> Maps the upstream items into SingleSources and subscribes to them one
> after the other succeeds, emits their success values or terminates
> immediately if either this Flowable or the current inner SingleSource
> fail.

```
Flowable.fromArray("a","b","c","d")
    .concatMapSingle(item -> /* Send item to backend */)
```